# PowerShell Change Variable in ScriptBlock

Tags: xaml, powershell

I'm trying to change a variable inside a ScriptBlock.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$Window.Add_SourceInitialized( {
    $timer = new-object System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
    $timer.Interval = [TimeSpan]"0:0:0.25"
    $timer.Add_Tick( $updateBlock )
    $timer.Start()
 } )
 $count = 0
 $updateBlock = { Write-Host $count; $count++; Write-Host $count}
```

The Output is a repeating sequence of 0 and 1. So how do I access the variable and not only a copy of it?

Comment: `$count++` -> `([ref]$count).Value++`

Comment: thansk, that worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you modify `$count` inside the scope of the ScriptBlock, a local copy is created, and the original `$Count` variable in the parent scope is left untouched.

There are a few ways to modify `$count` in the parent scope, either with an explicit scope qualifier:

```
$updateBlock = { Write-Host $count; $script:count++; Write-Host $count}
```

Or by retrieving the variable with `Get-Variable` and the relative `-Scope` parameter (`-Scope 1` refers to the immediate parent scope):

```
$updateBlock = { Write-Host $count; (Get-Variable -Scope 1 -Name count).Value++; Write-Host $count}
```

Or (as [pointed out by @PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054075/powershell-change-variable-in-scriptblock#comment65457616_39054075)), use the `[ref]` keyword:

```
 $updateBlock = { Write-Host $count; ([ref]$count).Value++; Write-Host $count}
```

Comment: idk why `$script:` does not work for me, but `Get-Variable` and `[ref]` work well